# mtl, reader, exceptt & stacking order

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

So this is going to be a bit long, because I'm not sure how to frame this question more generally. The good news is that I have a code sample at the bottom of the question, the idea is just to make it build & elegant :-)

I have a couple of functions which have signatures like:

```
calledFunction
  :: (MonadReader env m, HasToken env, MonadIO m)
  => m (Either MyError MyResult)

calledFunction2
  :: (MonadReader env m, HasToken env, MonadIO m)
  => m (Either MyError MyResult2)
```

And I'd like to get in the end a result of type `ExceptT String IO MyResult3` which I get by combining `MyResult` & `MyResult2`.

Now it's very nice that `calledFunction` returns an `Either` because I can leverage:

```
ExceptT :: m (Either e a) -> ExceptT e m a
```

And I just type `EitherT calledFunction` and I won't have anymore `m (Either MyError MyResult)` but straight `ExceptT MyError m MyResult)`. Progress!

But I also need to give to `calledFunction` the reader context it wants. Now, I would do that with `runReaderT`. I have now come to the `ExceptT MyError m MyResult` transformer stack, so naturally the `ReaderT` should go where the `m` is.. So `ExceptT MyError (ReaderT Config IO) MyResult`...

Except, how do I 'fill in' the readerT with the value to read, since it's at the bottom of the transformer stack? And if I reverse the stack to have the reader at the toplevel, then `runReaderT` comes naturally, but I don't see how to use `EitherT` to transform my `Either` in an `ExceptT` elegantly...

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Error -- 'error' package

class HasToken a where
    getToken :: a -> String
data Config = Config String
instance HasToken Config where
    getToken (Config x) = x

data MyError = MyError String deriving Show
data MyResult = MyResult String
data MyResult2 = MyResult2 String

data MyResult3 = MyResult3 MyResult MyResult2

calledFunction
  :: (MonadReader env m, HasToken env, MonadIO m)
  => m (Either MyError MyResult)
calledFunction = undefined

calledFunction2
  :: (MonadReader env m, HasToken env, MonadIO m)
  => m (Either MyError MyResult2)
calledFunction2 = undefined

cfg = Config "test"

main = undefined

test :: ExceptT MyError IO MyResult3
test = do
    -- calling runReaderT each time defeats the purpose..
    r1 <- ExceptT (runReaderT calledFunction cfg)
    r2 <- ExceptT (runReaderT calledFunction2 cfg)
    return $ MyResult3 r1 r2

test1 = runReaderT test2 cfg

test2 :: ReaderT Config (ExceptT MyError IO) MyResult3
test2 = do
    -- how to make this compile?
    let cfg = Config "test"
    r1 <- ExceptT calledFunction
    r2 <- ExceptT calledFunction2
    return $ MyResult3 r1 r2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`hoist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) from [`Control.Monad.Morph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html) to run the `Reader` below the `ExceptT`:

```
ghci> let foo = undefined :: ExceptT () (ReaderT () IO) ()
ghci> :t hoist (flip runReaderT ()) foo
hoist (flip runReaderT ()) foo :: ExceptT () IO ()
```

It's also easy to do it yourself, you just have to unwrap with `runExceptT`, supply the environment with `runReader`, and re-wrap the result in the `ExceptT` constructor:

```
ghci> :t \env -> ExceptT . flip runReaderT env . runExceptT
\env -> ExceptT . flip runReaderT env . runExceptT
    :: r -> ExceptT e (ReaderT r m) a -> ExceptT e m a
```

Comment: Right, so this works:  `test = hoist (flip runReaderT cfg) $ do ...`. Thank you!